# The halting problem and Diophantine equation

Tags: reference-request, computability

The **halting problem** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) has been shown to be equivalent to the problem of determining whether a given Diophantine equation has solutions.

I need to see a reference about this statement

Comment: There are plenty references here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_set

Comment: @Wojowu: I need the one specified for the halting problem.

Comment: @Germany, there will not be one particular equation. Each Turing machine can be translated into a Diophantine equation, and then the existence of a solution to that equation is equivalent to that particular Turing machine halting.

Comment: The one-way proof is easy: for a given equation, write an algorithm that tries all possibilities exhaustively and stops on a solution. If you had a Halting Test, you could use it to check the existence of a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deciding whether a given Diophantine equation has a solution is [Hilbert's tenth problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_tenth_problem).

What you're looking for is [Matiyasevich's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_set#Matiyasevich's_theorem)

A good reference is [this survey](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.0441.pdf) from Jochen Koenigsmann.